# Ember Adapter Receive Data via Ajax Post

Tags: ajax, ember.js

I am new to Ember and this is my first question on stackoverflow. I am working on client side of an Ember project and I need to pull JSON data from a Rest Api. Previously I could extract data given as below:

//app\adapters\product.js

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

host:"http://10.1.7.13,
pathForType(){
 return "content.php?method=list&pr1=product&pr2=all&uname=aaa&upass=1234";    }});
```

// app\serializers\product.js

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

normalizeResponse (store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType){

payload={
    products:payload
};
return this._super(store,primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType)
```

}
});

Then the url for backend changed and now username and userpassword are not params for url but send in as form data.

In the new form the url for list products is "http://10.1.7.13/content.php?method=list&pr1=product&pr2=all"

Although if I just access with this url page gives warning as username and userpassword is not defined. So I cant reach json data.

But if I send an ajax post request as below

```
 $.ajax({

    type:"POST",

    url: "http://10.1.7.13/content.php?method=list&pr1=product&pr2=all",

    data: {
    "uname":"aaa",
    "upass":1234
    },

    success: function(response){

    console.log(response);
    }
});
```

I can see my JSON data as I have given username and password as form data. 
My question is where can I call this ajax post and how can I load the response to product model? Ideally I want to call on adapter and send response to serializer then add that to my model like before. But I looked into adapter methods and did not see one that helps me. I am new to rest api so could you tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the adapter's **findAll** method which is used to GET multiple records.  In this case, you need to modify the HTTP method from GET to POST to pass the data.

I'm assuming you are using the DS.RESTAdapter, so the code would be:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   host: "http://10.1.7.13",

   pathForType() {
     return "content.php?method=list&pr1=product&pr2=all";
   },

   findAll(store, type, sinceToken, snapshotRecordArray) {
     let query = this.buildQuery(snapshotRecordArray);
     let url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, null, snapshotRecordArray, 'findAll');

     return this.ajax(url, "POST", { data: {uname: "aaa", upass: "1234"} });
    }
 });
```

I assumed the password was a string in your post. If your serializer could use the data prior to the URL change, it should still work.

When trying to figure out what adapter customizations are needed, I will paste in the Ember Data source code for the [methods](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.18/classes/DS.RESTAdapter) into a custom adapter and step through the code.  A good way to learn the internals.  Same thing for serializer modifications

As a final note, hardcoding usernames and passwords in your code is insecure.  I don't know if this was just for the example but wanted to call it out.